# Laravel Authentication not working multiple controllers

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, middleware, controllers

Hey guys i am newly working on Laravel. I am facing a problem regarding authentication.
Its that whenever i try to authenticate a user and redirect it to a view of a specific controller it works fine but then when i try to open the other view the user authentication does not work ( user logs out ). basically the issue is i have two controllers so if i redirects from authentication to any one of them the other one doesnt have the user.
I hope i have explained my problem clearly

**Route List : Result**
[Route List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otj79.png)

**Main page routes are the ones that i am working with... others are just dummy as for now**

This is my authentication class

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class Authenticate
{
/**
 * The Guard implementation.
 *
 * @var Guard
 */
protected $auth;



public function __construct(Guard $auth)
{
    $this->auth = $auth;
}

/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->auth->guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return redirect()->guest('/');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
}
```

This is the Index Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class IndexPageController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */

public function __construct()
{

    $this->middleware('auth');

}




public function index()
{

   $user = Auth::user()->firstOrFail();
    return view('index')
        ->with(compact('user'));


    //
}
```

This is the UserProfileController

```
 <?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;

 use App\Http\Requests;
 use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
 use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class UserProfileController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */


public function __construct()
{

    $this->middleware('auth');

}


public function index()
{

    $user = Auth::user()->firstOrFail();


    return view('profile.index')
        ->with(compact('user'));
    //
}
```

Routes

```
 <?php


use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

/*Welcome Page routes */


Route::get('/' , function(){
    return view('auth.login');
});


Route::get('user/logout' , function(){
    Auth::logout();
return redirect('/');
});


Route::post('user/do-login' , 'Auth\AuthController@doLogin');

Route::get('user/create' , 'Auth\AuthController@createUser');

/*---------------------------*/


/*Welcome Page AJAX routes*/
Route::get('/checkAvailibility' , 'WelcomePageController@usercheck');







/*---------------------------*/



/*Images Routes*/
Route::post('image/do-upload' ,'GalleryController@doImageUpload');
Route::post('gallery/save' , 'GalleryController@saveGallery');

Route::get('gallery/list' , 'GalleryController@viewGalleryList');
Route::get('gallery/view/{id}' , 'GalleryController@viewGalleryPics');
Route::get('gallery/delete/{id}' , 'GalleryController@deleteGallery');
/*---------------------------*/


/*Event Routes */

Route::post('create/Image-Upload' , 'CreateEventFormController@ImageUpload');
Route::post('create' , 'CreateEventFormController@store');


Route::get('create/event-image' , 'CreateEventFormController@createEventFormImage');
Route::post('create/event-image' , 'CreateEventFormController@UploadEventImg');

Route::get('create' , 'CreateEventFormController@create');

Route::get('event/{id}' , [ 'as' => 'event_list' , 'uses' => 'CreateEventFormController@show']);


/*---------------------------*/




/*-------------- Main Page Routes -------------------*/


Route::get('event/{id}' , [ 'as' => 'event_list' , 'uses' => 'CreateEventFormController@show']);


Route::get('index' ,[ 'as' => 'index' , 'uses' => 'IndexPageController@index']);




/*-------------- END -------------------*/






/*-------------- Main Page Routes -------------------*/


Route::get('profile' , 'UserProfileController@index');
Route::get('profile/{id}' , 'IndexPageController@show');


/*-------------- END -------------------*/









Route::get('/email', function () {

    $data = array(
        'name' => "Learning Laravel",
    );

    Mail::send('emails.test', $data, function ($message) {

        $message->from('yourEmail@domain.com', 'Learning Laravel');

        $message->to('yourEmail@domain.com')->subject('Learning Laravel test email');

    });

    return "Your email has been sent successfully";

});
```

Comment: Which version of Laravel?

Comment: Can you update the question with your controller methods too?

Comment: Can you please include your routes.php file

Comment: Okay i have updated with the controllers and routes

Comment: Main page routes are the ones that i am working with... others are just dummy as for now..

Comment: can you also post php artisan route:list results?

Comment: added the image of route list result..

Comment: Thanks. The middlewares look correct so that's probably not the issue. Not sure if it's related to 5.1. So you're saying if you go to profile/1 you're sent back to login page?

Comment: yes exactly that is my problem

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that there is something with your `AuthController.php`.

Are you by any chance using `Auth::attempt()` to authenticate? If so, I have experienced problems in the past where echoing something out after authenticating causes problems.

Another possibility is that something is going wrong with storing the session. It could be something as simple as the session not being saved/written.

Comment: I am usin Auth atemp